# Flutter deserialize class if not all porperties are present in json string

Tags: json, flutter, serialization

I have a calls like so:

```
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';
class Article {
  Decimal price;
  Decimal minPrice;

  Article(
      {this.price,
      this.minPrice});

  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Article(
        price: Decimal.parse(json['price'].toString())minPrice: Decimal.parse(json['minPrice'].toString() ?? ""));
  }
```

}

And i would like to create my objects from a json file, but the minPrice property is not available for all articles. So deserilaization fails.

Can someone tell how i can check if this property is in the json string?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: A `Map` has a method `containsKey`, returning true when the key is present in the map. You could do something like this: `price: json.containsKey('price') ? Decimal.parse(json['price'].toString()) : null` (or any other default you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `json["price"] == null` to check

code snippet

```
factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Article(
        price: json["price"] == null ? null : Decimal.parse(json["price"]),
        minPrice:
            json["minPrice"] == null ? null : Decimal.parse(json["minPrice"]),
      );

 String jsonString1 = '''
    {
    "price":"12.3",
    "minPrice" : "30.1"
}
    ''';

    String jsonString2 = '''
    {
    "price":"12.9"
}
    ''';
```

output

```
I/flutter (16685): price 12.3 minPrice 30.1
I/flutter (16685): price 12.9 minPrice null
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:decimal/decimal.dart';

Article articleFromJson(String str) => Article.fromJson(json.decode(str));

class Article {
  Decimal price;
  Decimal minPrice;

  Article({
    this.price,
    this.minPrice,
  });

  factory Article.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Article(
        price: json["price"] == null ? null : Decimal.parse(json["price"]),
        minPrice:
            json["minPrice"] == null ? null : Decimal.parse(json["minPrice"]),
      );
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    String jsonString1 = '''
    {
    "price":"12.3",
    "minPrice" : "30.1"
}
    ''';
    Article article1 = articleFromJson(jsonString1);
    print('price ${article1.price} minPrice ${article1.minPrice}');

    String jsonString2 = '''
    {
    "price":"12.9"
}
    ''';
    Article article2 = articleFromJson(jsonString2);
    print('price ${article2.price} minPrice ${article2.minPrice}');

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use this library https://github.com/k-paxian/dart-json-mapper.
Of course if you don't like to implement `.fromJson`methods for all your model classes manually and having fun with debugging them later.